# Adding up field values in a SP out of the box form

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a requirement from a client to show the combined value of a series of calculated fields *within* an Out of the Box SharePoint online form. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another calculated column and use the series of calculated fields in the formula.

For example:

I have two calculated fields that display two strings named *CAL1* and *CAL2*. To combine the two strings, we create another calculated column named *CAL3* and use the formula

```
CAL3 = CONCATENATE([CAL1]," ",[CAL2])
```

So that *CAL3* will display the combined strings of the two fields.

[image]

Another example:

```
CAL1 = Today() (Date and Time)
CAL2 = “7”
CAL3 = [CAL1] + [CAL2] (Date and Time)
```

[image]

Reference:
[Calculated Field Formulas.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)#text-formulas)

Comment: Thanks, but would I be able to display the results in the form not the list?

Comment: @Dazza You can hide the column from the current list view via Switch view options on the menu > Edit current view and then deselect the calculated column. The column will not be visible in the list but remains in the list form.